# when I try to insert an image in Texmaker, it goes wrong

Tags: errors, texmaker

Here is the code I used

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{0.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I typed like this but there is an error at line 2 which is 
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].

Comment: Drop your use of `\end{frame}`.

Comment: i dropped \end{frame} but it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

You should drop `\end{frame}`, since you dont use `\begin{frame}`.
Also your `\documentclass` arguments should be something like this:

`\documentclass{article}`

The []-brackets are for further options like `a4paper`.

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{0.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```